# App crashes when displaying casted int with Toast

Tags: java, android, casting, toast

I have an Android App calling a PHP script, which returns 0 (FALSE) or 1 (TRUE) - unfortunately as a string. So in my Java Code I have the variable `String result` which is either "0" or "1". I know (thanks to you guys here) that this string can start with the BOM, so I remove it, if it does.

It is not really necessary but let's say I'd feel better if I had that result as an integer not as a string. The casting from string to int named `code` seems to work. At least I do not see anything happen.

But when I want to use the casted int like `if (code == 1)` or display it via Toast, my app crashes.
I can show with `Toast` that `result == "1"` and that `result.length() == 1` so I do not see how I can possibly fail casting this string to int:

```
String result = postData("some stuff I send to PHP");

if (result.codePointAt(0) == 65279) // which is the BOM
   {result = result.substring(1, result.length());}

int code = Integer.parseInt(result); // <- does not crash here...

// but here...
Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this, code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I also tried using `valueOf()` and adding `.toString()` but it just keeps crashing. What am I missing here?

Comment: post logcat messages... error msg..

Comment: Try this - Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this,Integer.toString(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Thank you all! The problem really was that Toast cannot display pure integers. I did just assume it could because I did this hundreds of times, but they were always enclosed in strings.
Using the integer as usual in a code like `if (code == 0)` did actually work, I just forgot to remove the "wrong" Toast before doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Use the following way to show toast 
    Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this, ""+code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Concatenation of String and int should work . But IMO this will be better - Integer.toString(code) or String.valueOf(code).

Comment: what is special in your answer sir? OP already saying that he tried with tostring.......

Comment: then what does mean by ""+code isn't it create a string of code, using concat functionality? SO it should be equal to toString(), right? or is there something I am missing

Comment: i am also face one time this problem than i have use + operator to resolve this issue with Integer value.

Answer (score 2):

`Toast.makeText` requires a `String(CharSequence)` or an `int` but this `int` represents the resource id of the string resource to use (ex: `R.string.app_name`)

Try instead :

```
Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this, String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this, String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)

public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.

Parameters

```
context      The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
text         The text to show. Can be formatted text.
duration     How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

So use  String valueOf(code) as the second parameter to makeText(params)

Returns the string representation of the integer (code) argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Toast** library [Toast.makeText(Context, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) uses that integer as Resource ID to Find a String in your resources.
Now since you don't have a resource with the same integer the function throws `Resources.NotFoundException` .

So to display your **int** value you have to change it back to text.

```
Toast.makeText(ListView_Confirmation.this, String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In android Api, the constructor of a toast is :
Toast.makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)

"resId" is the reference of your String but not a String Object:

example: resId= R.string.helloworld